# A script to update all columns in a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am using PHP to manipulate information in my MySQL database. However I am looking for a way to update a table (all records need to be updated) based on information within another table.

For example I have a list of products lets say 10 each with a unique id stored in a products table. I have a purchases table which has the same product ID and the amount of purchases done for each product. I want to update each product in the products table to reflect the total purchases made for each product and store it in a column called instock which is part of the products table.

How can this be done?

Comment: Show us the tables structures, sample data in them and tell, what did you try.

Comment: Also you might want to search the site before doing that

Comment: @kern elliott By 'database', I guess you meant 'table'. Even so, I don't see where all these columns come into it. Consider providing a sqlfiddle.

Comment: _One script to rule them all_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, you're dealing with a stock-count. When an item is purchased (represented by a entry in the `Products` table) then the stock count figure should be decreased. This should happen within the same transaction as the new entry to the `Products` table to keep your data consistent. I would recommend using a Trigger on the table to implement this. You'll find lots of information about implementing triggers in MySQL on this site. A trigger you could use might look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_stock_count
    BEFORE INSERT ON Purchases
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE Products SET stock_count = stock_count - NEW.quantity_ordered
            WHERE product_id = NEW.product_id;
    END;
```

This trigger doesn't take into account that there might not be enough stock of a product, nor does it handle updates or deletes on the `Purchases` table but it could be modified to do so.

Comment: the info is a bit off for the example I had in mind but I understand how I can use this to use in my case thanks